# Gremlin - connect vertices a and b where a.x is within b.y values

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Sample graph def:

```
g.addV("foo").property("x", "a")
g.addV("bar").property(set, "y", "a").property(set, "y", "b").property(set, "y", "c")
```

I need to add an edge b/w `foo` and `bar` vertices where bar.y CONTAINS foo.x

I'm trying this query, but it throws an error

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("bar").as("bar").V().hasLabel("foo").as("foo").where("foo", eq("bar")).by("x").by("y").addE("contains").from("bar").to("foo").Iterate()
Multiple properties exist for the provided key, use Vertex.properties(y)
```

I've tried many variations but cannot get it to work. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach you can try:

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("bar").as("bar").
......1>   V().hasLabel("foo").as("foo").
......2>   where(within("bar")).by('x').by(values('y').fold())    

==>v[0]
```